# How to check maths result correct or not correct

Tags: tcl

How to catch compute expression but still continue process until done and below the script;

```
set vars {33 53 65t 43 word 55 d}
foreach varList $vars {
 if {[expr {$varList / $varList}] == 1} {    ;#I am stuck maths here if its not numerics string
   set mathVar $varList
 } else {
   set mathVar "Invalid"
 }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want [`string is integer`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M10)

```
foreach var $vars {
    if {[string is integer -strict $var]} {
        set mathvar $var
    } else {
        puts "not an integer: $var"
        set mathvar 0     ;# or some default value
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried [string is double -strict $var] but bad option "is" and the massage said: must be compare, first, index, last, length, match, range, tolower, toupper, trim, trimleft, trimright, wordend, or wordstart. Any another determine to do this..

Comment: @Andre: Which Tcl version are you using?

Comment: I am using 8.5. Could use regexp ?

Comment: @Andre the error message you get for ``string is`` indicates that you are using Tcl 7.x. Please check the Tcl version you are running with ``[info tclversion]``. If this indeed 7.x you can use ``catch`` to find if you get an error and handle properly. ``[string is]`` should work in Tcl 8.5

Comment: I wonder if he's actually using one of the non-standard Tcl versions. Those might be missing `string is`…

Comment: Yes, I am using version 8.5. I have try using regexp "[regexp {\d+} $var]" and its work but still not perfect to filter it. Can you modify this regexpr because I am still confuse around regexp.  I just need to matches a string representing numeric values (integer, float/real format) greater 0.